# Combine results of column one Then sum column 2 to list total for each entry in column one

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am bit of Bash newbie, so please bear with me here.

I have a text file dumped by another software (that I have no control over) listing each user with number of times accessing certain resource that looks like this:

```
Jim 109
Bob 94
John 92
Sean 91
Mark 85
Richard 84
Jim  79
Bob  70
John 67
Sean 62
Mark 59
Richard 58
Jim  57
Bob  55
John 49
Sean 48
Mark 46
.
.
.
```

My goal here  is to get an output like this.

```
Jim  [Total for Jim]
Bob  [Total for Bob]
John [Total for John]
```

And so on.

Names change each time I run the query in the software, so static search on each name and then piping through wc does not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) :) Pipe the output of your program to the following `awk` script:

```
your_program | awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(name in a)print name " " a[name]}'
```

Output:

```
Sean 201
Bob 219
Jim 245
Mark 190
Richard 142
John 208
```

The `awk` script itself can be explained better in this format:

```
# executed on each line
{
  # 'a' is an array. It will be initialized 
  # as an empty array by awk on it's first usage
  # '$1' contains the first column - the name
  # '$2' contains the second column - the amount
  #
  #  on every line the total score of 'name' 
  #  will be incremented  by 'amount'
  a[$1]+=$2
}
# executed at the end of input
END{
  # print every name and its score
  for(name in a)print name " " a[name]
}
```

Note, to get the output sorted by score, you can add another pipe to `sort -r -k2`. `-r -k2` sorts the by the second column in reverse order:

```
your_program | awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(n in a)print n" "a[n]}' | sort -r -k2
```

Output:

```
Jim 245
Bob 219
John 208
Sean 201
Mark 190
Richard 142
```

Comment: That worked like a champ. Thank you!
I was going the loooong way, piping the out put to awk '{print $2}', reading that into a variable and then hit the wall trying to sum the variable and list the results. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you again for your time, patience, explanation and assistance. I hope I can return the favor one day. This made my day. I was begging to get frustrated because of the wrong approach in using awk, and then aggravated the problem further by trying to re-invent the wheel using what seems to be now unnecessary for i nested loops trying to sum the occurrences. Pretty much wasted couple of hours before I gave up. Really appreciated. Words cannot explain how thankful I am.

Comment: Don't worry! :) It was really fun to answer this. I would say I'm at most intermediate in awk and like learning more by solving problems here. awk is really cooool like many tools available in the UNIX/Linux command line. Pipe them together and you can do things you can't imagine - with one line! :)

Answer (score 4):

Pure Bash:

```
declare -A result                 # an associative array

while read name value; do
  ((result[$name]+=value))
done < "$infile"

for name in ${!result[*]}; do
  printf  "%-10s%10d\n"  $name  ${result[$name]}
done
```

If the first 'done' has no redirection from an input file
this script can be used with a pipe:

```
your_program | ./script.sh
```

and sorting the output

```
your_program | ./script.sh | sort
```

The output:

```
Bob              219
Richard          142
Jim              245
Mark             190
John             208
Sean             201
```

Comment: @fgm. Thanks for the bash solution. That will certainly help me learn more bash as I am still a newbie. Thanks folks, I really appreciate all the assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

*GNU* [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

```
datamash -W -s -g1 sum 2 < input.txt
```

Output:

```
Bob 219
Jim 245
John    208
Mark    190
Richard 142
Sean    201
```

Comment: I was not aware of datamash. Thanks.